# How to display background image by using python cgi

Tags: python, cgi

i just started working on small web server programming .when i tried to display background image by using python cgi script ,image is not coming at the background of web page .

print('') is line by which i,m trying to 
load background image.(by the way image folder is not in the cgi-bin folder).
i,m using python3

Comment: You need to include your actual code so we can see it and tell what is the problem in it

Comment: Not in the comment. Edit your question with this code.